# Why are mediums always represented as straight and parallel lines in Ray optics?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I have been reading Ray Optics lately and I always see that the interface between mediums are always represented as Straight lines in ray diagrams. There is no mention that they are considering an infinitesimally small portion of the medium. Is that what it is? Or is there some other reason?

I am intrigued because they not only draw the interface of two mediums straight and parallel in ray diagrams but also take advantage of the fact and make use of the law of transverses and all! What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

PS:- Here is an example:-

[image: Refraction]

See that interface between glass and air? Why is it always straight in all the ray diagrams in all the textbooks I see? Why not make it curved or just plain not flat? That is my question.

Comment: This diagram is teaching you the very important concept of *refraction*. Refraction also happens on curved surfaces but the additional complexity will obscure the same underlying mechanism.

Comment: Lenses can be analyzed with ray optics, and lenses necessarily have curved surfaces. If none of your optics textbooks include lenses, you should look for some better textbooks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is based on a mistaken assumption. In introductory texts you start with "keeping it simple" - flat surfaces, parallel lines - until you get comfortable with that.

And then you add prisms. Surfaces are no longer parallel, but still flat.

And then you add lenses. And convex/concave mirrors. They are curved but amenable to (analytical) ray tracing. With the "thin lens" assumption things work well. I guess you just haven't got to that chapter yet.

Then your lenses get thicker, giving rise to additional aberrations: spherical, chromatic, ...

Finally you get ground surfaces - roughened surfaces have insanely complex behavior. That typically gets tackled using Monte Carlo simulation - and even then the results of that "stochastic ray tracing" is often only very approximate.

Life is simple when everything is still flat and straight. Enjoy it while it lasts.

Comment: "Life is simple when everything is still flat and straight." -- but the view isn't as nice.

Comment: @DavidRicherby what are you talking about. I grew up in Holland...